# Joomla - MVC Model/View registration

Tags: php, joomla

I have a component that I need to register a second view for.  When I encode my url to set the view varialbe from:

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php?option=com_mycom&view=view1
```

to

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php?option=com_mycom&view=view2
```

View2 will not display.

Do I need to register the second view in the controller?  Can you point me to a reference?  Google searches have come up nill.

**EDIT**

The view2 code:

```
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

jimport( 'joomla.application.component.view');

/**
 * HTML View class for the mls Component
 *
 * @package    UniversalDynamicMedia.com
 * @subpackage  Components
 */
class mlsViewlist extends JView
{
function display($tpl = null)
{
    $model = &$this->getModel();
    $array = $model->mlsListData();
    $disparray =    foreach ($array as list($a,$b,$c,$d,$e)) {
                echo <tr><td>$a</td><td>$b</td><td>$c</td><td>$d</td><td>$e</td></tr>
            }
    $this->assignRef( 'disparray', $disparray );
    parent::display($tpl);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Why do you have `$` in the URL instead of `&`? Is that a typo in the question?

Comment: typo.  I have fixed the error.

Comment: You don't need to register the view so there must be a problem with your view2 code, show the view.html.php code.

Comment: I mean, that's what I thought, that it just found the view by the classname.  Even looking for examples, I could only find how to apply additional models to the view.

Comment: Your view is called `list` but your example URL shows `view2`

Comment: The encoded url was just an example.  I don't like to put my code up because people I feel like I'm taking advantage of people because they usually just alter the code for me.  I would rather understand the concept.  I just couldn't find any examples of apply additional views to a component, but from what you're telling me, such a method doesn't exist, but that is should be taken care of in the class name, correct?  Which is what I already thought from my research, but it still wasn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error here:

```
echo <tr><td>$a</td><td>$b</td><td>$c</td><td>$d</td><td>$e</td></tr>
```

Should be

```
echo "<tr><td>$a</td><td>$b</td><td>$c</td><td>$d</td><td>$e</td></tr>";
```

You need quotes when echoing string literals. You shouldn't even be echoing anything here though. All output should be done in the view's Default.php not view.html.php. The reason for this is because Joomla needs to output everything before your component (ie page header) first.

Comment: Ok, commented out all the invalid code, had it do just an `echo` string and it works.  Guess I need to learn some php. :/  Any reference on creating a `foreach()` with an array from the model?

Comment: :) be sure to keep an eye on your error log too because that will tell you where any syntax errors are.